# In array not matching with array

Tags: php

```
$blockon2 = array("opi-infinite-shine", "opi-gel", "cnd-vinylux", "opi");

var_dump(in_array(array("opi-infinite-shine", "opi-gel"), $blockon2, true));
// returns false
```

Someone has some idea of why it's returning false? Thanks!

---

It searchs for the exactly matching, so to return true is necessary an array inside $blockon2 with the needle  ($blockon2[]= array("opi-infinite-shine", "opi-gel"))

Comment: Why are you casting an array to an array?

Comment: I read a comment on stack overflow saying to try this. but it does not work with or without the cast.

Comment: What you think that in_array does?

Comment: check the values of the first array, to see if any of them is on the second array, returning true or false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) instead:

```
$blockon2 = array("opi-infinite-shine", "opi-gel", "cnd-vinylux", "opi");

var_dump(!(bool)array_diff(array("opi-infinite-shine", "opi-gel"), $blockon2));
```

It will return true if all array entries present in original array

Or if you need to check if any of values exist try [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

```
$blockon2 = array("opi-infinite-shine", "opi-gel", "cnd-vinylux", "opi");

var_dump((bool)array_intersect(array("opi-infinite-shine", "opi-gel"), $blockon2));
```

Comment: _You can't use array as needle in in_array_ - untrue, `var_dump(in_array(array(1,2), array(array(1,2),array(3,4)), true));` is `true`

Comment: Quoted from PHP.net `Example #3 in_array() with an array as needle`. You can use array as needle.

Comment: Ok, my bad. Updated my answer

Comment: I just need 1 entry to be present, not all of them.

Comment: You are right, I should use array_diff, since in array looks for the exactly match, so I can't give different values for the needle.

Comment: Updated my answer with solution.

Comment: Thank you miller, I'm going to use your answer for sure, but I managed to do like that: $boncheck = false;
  foreach($blockon2 as $bon){
   if($boncheck == false)
    $boncheck = in_array($bon, $categoriestocount, true);    
  
  }

Comment: Ok, no problem. Your solution is also going to work. Don't forget to add `break;` to stop iterating after condition was met.